# Laravel Nova: Partition to display other table's column

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova partition to show an amount of items per category.

```
public function calculate(Request $request) {
   return $this->count($request, Item::class, 'category_id');
}
```

This works fine, but displays on the screen the category_id of course.

[image]
I would rather want to show the category_name.

The model is built as follows:

```
class Item extends Model 
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
 }
```

and

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }   
}
```

Also, I have in the Nova Category resource defined the following:

```
public static $title = 'category_name';
```

How can I show the category name instead of the category id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#partition-metrics)

> Often, the column values that divide your partition metrics into
>   groups will be simple keys, and not something that is "human
>   friendly". Or, if you are displaying a partition metric grouped by a
>   column that is a boolean, Nova will display your group labels as "0"
>   and "1". For this reason, Nova allows you to provide a Closure that
>   formats the label into something more readable:

```
/**
 * Calculate the value of the metric.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->count($request, User::class, 'stripe_plan')
            ->label(function ($value) {
                switch ($value) {
                    case null:
                        return 'None';
                    default:
                        return ucfirst($value);
                }
            });
}
```

So, in your case, it would be something like this:

```
/**
 * Calculate the value of the metric.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->count($request, Item::class, 'category_id');
        ->label(function ($value) {
            // Get your category name here
            // For example: return \App\Category::find($value)->name; 
        });
}
```

Comment: That's what I had done already (as part of something else), but this does not show the name unfortunately (in the partition).

Comment: Ah right, edited my answer for a possible implementation.

Comment: Super. Your suggestion works, however you need to add the return statement. So it will be "return Category::find($value)->category_name;". Suggest you edit the answer and I will accept it. Thanks mate!